# Obteniendo impares en rango de una lista

Tags: python

Quiero obtener los números impares de un rango de una lista (los obtuve sin querer)
Le indico que si el número es divisible por 2 me devuelve los impares.
??

```
def nroimpares():
  listaImpar = []
  for numero in range (1, 101):
    if numero % 2:
        listaImpar.append(numero)
 return listaImpar

 print(nroimpares())
```

Comment: Cuál es exactamente la pregunta?

Comment: Por qué si le digo " Si el numero es divisible por dos"  me devuelve los impares? Soy total novato como verás! Gracias

Comment: Porque la expresión `numero % 2` da resto 1 con los impares, y se evalúa como `true`. Prueba con `numero % 2 == 0` y verás que te imprime los pares...

Comment: Ahora si! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Se que esta bastante claro y resuelto ya, pero por las dudas lo dire. La expresion numero1 % numero2 devuelve el resto de dividir ambos numeros, que no es lo mismo que decir si es divisible o no por numero2 (lo cual no existe en Python). Por ejemplo 11 % 3 devuelve resto 2. Despues, lo que hace el if, es convertir el numero en true o false (0 es false y el resto de numeros es true)

Answer (score 0):

Solo es una forma de escribirlo.
la formula o division %
debuelve el residuo o en otros paises el resto, ejemplo grafico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es lo que queda de una división y cuando es numero es par siempre será 0

```
def nroimpares():
  listaImpar = []
  for numero in range (1, 101):
    if numero % 2 !=0:
        listaImpar.append(numero)
  return listaImpar


print(nroimpares())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por eso la expresion `if 2 % 2` siempre da como resultado 0

OJO la expresion `if numero % 2:` funcionara pues el residuo es 0 para los par y python lo interpreta 0 como false

Comment: ¿Es realmente repasar la *división*? No estamos en 3° básico.

Comment: tu no, pero muchos no lo tienen claro, puede que a ti no te sirva pero a las personas que no lo saben les ayuda muchísimo, y es mejor cuando te enseñan con peras y manzanas.

Comment: No se qué puede estar haciendo en este sitio alguien que no conoce la división ...

Comment: aprendiendo, como todos los que entran al sitio, o agrandando su ego como muchos...

Answer (score 0):

Este código te servirá:

```
impares = [x for x in range(1, 101) if x % 2]
```

Es una comprensión de listas que recorre el rango 1 a 101 filtrando sólo los elementos impares.

El operador "%" retorna el resto de la división entre `x` y 2. Si es cero, el número es par; si es cualquier otro valor, es impar.